usage of pbkdf2 with browser's webcrypto api
how to use the pbkdf2 derivation function in the (firefox) browser's webcrypto api to obtain the same result as the sjcl.misc.pbkdf2 function (stanford javascript crypto library) or the “derive pbkdf2 key” operation in cyberchef ?
in both cases, the result is 1dee9f26ad603dc9260a3071242ef1a46270a975aff83c2178ff88974756d83b :

case 1

sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(sjcl.misc.pbkdf2('test', 'test', 10000, 256));


case 2

https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Derive_PBKDF2_key(%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'test'%7D,256,10000,'SHA256',%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'test'%7D)
I tried to get inspiration from various examples found on the internet, but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Please post your WebCrypto code and describe the problem.

I was using the web-crypto/derive-bits/pbkdf2.js example provided by dom-example and thought the problem came from the getKeyMaterial function which returns window.crypto.subtle.importKey - which I can't get the result of - but I've just realized that it was actually the number of iterations that was wrong ! 1e5 in the example whereas 1e4 for me !! that's not good for a first post on StackOverflow : sorry for the noise generated.

to finally answer my question, here's the modified code from the above example :
// web-crypto/derive-bits/pbkdf2.js @ dom-example
(() => {
  let salt;
  function getKeyMaterial() {
    const password = window.prompt("Enter your password"); // enter test at prompt
    const enc = new TextEncoder();
    return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "raw",
      enc.encode(password),
      {name: "PBKDF2"},
      false,
      ["deriveBits", "deriveKey"]
    );
  }
  async function getDerivedBits() {
    const keyMaterial = await getKeyMaterial();
//  salt = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16)); // change
    const textEncoder = new TextEncoder(); // change
    salt = textEncoder. encode("test"); // change
    const derivedBits = await window.crypto.subtle.deriveBits(
      {
        "name": "PBKDF2",
        salt: salt,
//        "iterations": 100000, // change
        "iterations": 10000, // change
        "hash": "SHA-256"
      },
      keyMaterial,
      256
    );
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(derivedBits, 0, 5);
    const derivedBitsValue = document.querySelector(".pbkdf2 .derived-bits-value");
    derivedBitsValue.classList.add("fade-in");
    derivedBitsValue.addEventListener("animationend", () => {
      derivedBitsValue.classList.remove("fade-in");
    }, { once: true });
    derivedBitsValue.textContent = `${buffer}...[${derivedBits.byteLength} bytes total]`;
  }
  const deriveBitsButton = document.querySelector(".pbkdf2 .derive-bits-button");
  deriveBitsButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    getDerivedBits();
  });
})();

